# be eligible for their support

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "be eligible for their support" mean "be qualified to get the support from the funders"?

> Next year, funders might place limits on how much they will pay. cOAlition S says that after July 2022, only publishers who’ve provided data to explain their OA fees under one of two ‘price and service transparency frameworks’ will **be eligible for their support**, and that cOAlition S will support only OA publication fees that are “fair and reasonable”.

> Source:  [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-00883-6)

Comment: only publishers who have done [certain necessary things] will be eligible for [financial] support from those "funders" mentioned at the beginning. Or perhaps it's support from "cOAlition S" - you can probably figure out which of those possible readings applies by looking at the *whole* context. It's not unambiguous from the fragment as given. But in this context, "to be qualified" (= "to qualify") and "to be eligible" are effectively equivalent and interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "be eligible for their support"

> "be qualified to get the support from the funders"

The two examples above have similar meanings in this context.

One of the synonyms of 'eligible is 'qualified', as we can find in

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/eligible

Comment: [Could you please write out how to pronounce your first name? This just interests me as I have noticed that Singaporean names and Thai names are sometimes vey long. :) (Then, I will delete this.)\